# How to remote debug a ASP.NET Core webAPI published in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, remote-debugging

I have followed these steps: [remote debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-computer?view=vs-2019)

But when I open Debug>attach to process menu and I select my IIS Server:4024. I don´t see the dotnet.exe process neither w3wp.exe

I see this in IIS Server

[image: webAPI Process]

[image: w3wp.ese]

Any idea, please?

Regards

Comment: How did you publish your ASP.NET Core app? FDD or SCD?

Comment: In my Visual Studio in Spanish I select "Independiente" what I think is SCD

Comment: I hope you first use .NET Core CLI to publish the binaries and test it out, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli In that way you can fully control what's being generated. Later when it is resolved you can go back to VS.

Comment: The app published in SCD works fine the problem I have is attaching de remote debugger

Comment: If you published as SCD, then you should never attach to `dotnet.exe`. Would you mind re-read everything about SCD? https://blog.lextudio.com/a-closer-look-at-asp-net-core-execution-model-b3c332f6ed1

Comment: Thanks but publishing in SCD Shouldn't I see the process of my application in VS? Can't I attach to that process, to api.exe? I have request incoming when I update the list of process but my api.exe does not appear